# Why I geeting java.lang.NullPointerException when a MockBean is executed?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito

I have the following service class (Spring Boot):

```
@Service
public class  MyService {
        
    @Autowired
    private DependedService dependedService;
            
    @Transactional
    public boolean saveMyDetails(Integer id, List<> myList) {
        
        dependedService.saveSomething(id, myList);
        ...
        return true;
    }
```

I've implemented a test method to assert that the service method return true. please note that
the requirement is to ignore the call to the depended service:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class  MyServiceTests {          
        
    @Mock
    private MyService myService = new MyService ();
    
    @MockBean
    private DependedService dependedService;
        
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        ...     
        ...     
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSaveMyDetails() {
        ...
        ... 
        doNothing().when(dependedService).saveSomething(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyList());                           
        when(myService.saveMyDetails(someId, someList)).thenCallRealMethod();       
        assertEquals(true, myService.saveMyDetails(someId, someList));
    }
```

When running the test it seems that the depended service is not initialized correctly and I'm not
sure what should it annotated with in the test class (in the service is a Autowired) the exception is thrown at the service layer:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke ... because "<local4>.dependedService" is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not instantiate `MyService` on your own since you are using Spring framework for testing. You are not allowing the framework to do its work.

There are at least two options:

1. In case if `MyService` bean should be a bean (not a mock), just remove the instantiation and add `@Autowired` annotation to let Spring inject the mocked bean into the service. In that case, since your MyService bean is a bean that you are testing and filling with mocks, MyService bean will not be a mock, so you don't have to call thenCallRealMethod.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @MockBean
    private DependedService dependedService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
    }

    @Test
    void testSaveMyDetails() {
        doNothing().when(dependedService).saveSomething(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyList());
        myService.saveMyDetails(someId, someList);
        assertTrue(myService.saveMyDetails(someId, someList));
    }
}
```

2. In case if you want to manage the service bean behaviour, you can use `@SpyBean` annotation. Just remove the instantiation and add the annotation.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class MyServiceTest {

    @SpyBean
    private MyService myService;

    @MockBean
    private DependedService dependedService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
       // I added this just to show that you have an 
       // ability to manage the service bean behaviour.
       // You can remove this.
       when(myService.saveMyDetails(someOtherId, someOtherList))
           .thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException());
    }

    @Test
    void testSaveMyDetails() {
        doNothing().when(dependedService).saveSomething(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyList());
        myService.saveMyDetails(someId, someList);
        assertTrue(myService.saveMyDetails(someId, someList));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a reason MyService is mocked. The service method is calling another method in the same service. the mock make everything mocked and then I'm allowing only the tested service method a real call.

Comment: In that case you can add `@SpyBean` along with `@Autowired` annotation and you will be able to rule your service bean

```@Autowired
    @SpyBean
    private MyService myService;```

Comment: Are you able to update your answer? I'm not familiar with "rule"

Comment: Sure, have already done that

Comment: I see, but the service method is calling method2 and I need to do doNothing for this method

Comment: I think it's working now just by adding @SpyBean cause I have different problen which is not related, thanks, I'll accept